# @Bean implementation in SpringBoot- Calling bean again

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-bean

I have created a bean used for login, as the user and password are common for all the users.

@Bean
Private String login(){
....
}

Only one instance is created for a single bean definition per Spring IoC container, and it satisfies my requirement.
Login method would provide the access token(keep-alive), and it is used for other calls.
Now, using Spring scheduler, I have to logout and login every month. So how can I call the login bean again?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add more details to the question and include code snippets wherever possible so that you will get meaningful answers

Comment: @Bean Private String login(){ .... } is 100% not your Java code; since it will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EnableScheduling` to your main Application class.

Then you will want to add the `@Scheduled` annotation to your bean.

```
@Bean @Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 1 * ?")  String login(){ .... }
```

That will run it at midnight (timezone of your server) on the 1st of each month.

Comment: @mathewthomas if that is the correct answer, can you mark it as correct?

Comment: Login() method is autowired (@Auttowire Login login), so when the schedular is executed the new values are not refreshed hence gives me error. Is there any way or can we refresh the application context.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't doing things right here.  A Bean is responsible for managing its own state, not via refreshing the application context.  Take a look how the Keycloak TokenMangaer does it; `getAccessToken()` method.  It will refresh the token when the last one is expired. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/integration/admin-client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/admin/client/token/TokenManager.java